# Incorrect element width change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'd like to create a card (using Bootstrap) with rules like this:

1. the card has a minimum width of 250px (card #1 - renders correctly)
2. if the first line is longer than 250px, then the card should increase its width, the line should not wrap around (card # 2 - the width does not increase enough, the line wraps)
3. if the left and right parts of the second line are longer than 250px, then the card should increase its width, the lines should not wrap (card #3 - the width does not increase, the lines wrap)
4. the third line always wraps and should not increase the width of the card (card #4 - the width increases)

[image]

Cards are also displayed incorrectly on the smartphone screen.

[image]

Why is my code not working correctly?

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-black m-2 p-2" style="min-width:250px;">
      <div class="">#1 Short string</div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Right</div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrap">Short wrapped string</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-black m-2 p-2" style="min-width:250px;">
      <div class="">#2 Very very very very very very very very long string</div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Right</div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrap">Short wrapped string</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-black m-2 p-2" style="min-width:250px;">
      <div class="">#3 Short string</div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div>Left left left left</div>
        <div>Right right right right</div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrap">Short wrapped string</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column border border-black m-2 p-2" style="min-width:250px;">
      <div class="">#4 Short string</div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Right</div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrap">Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long wrapped string</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use inline styles. As you can see, this results in much repetition, and if you change your mind you have a lot of work to do. Use a custom class or other CSS selector.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with div w-100

Remove

And the text will fill.

Comment: This look like comment, can you add more details?

Comment: If I remove "w-100" then card #4 expands to its full width, the text doesn't wrap.

Comment: Why people needs all done? Remove the class "w-100" all the places its in the code and it will work.

Comment: @felipe-v-r No, it won't work. I explained it. Apparently you didn't even try your recommendation. Removing w -100 the string "very long wrapped string" will increase the width of the card (it won't actually wrap). If you claim that it works, then provide the full code and the result of its execution in the sandbox, where I will see that the card does not increase its width.